# Why does ng-repeat behave weird with auto-incrementing id?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, auto-increment

I have a form that inserts into a MySQL database. 
POST requests and GET requests work perfectly.

I've decided to add an id column in the MySQL table. 
The SQL statement used to add my id column was: 
`ALTER TABLE thestuff ADD COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;`

Before I added the id column in the table, when I entered a date and content and pressed submit, the fetch would work perfectly and the date and content would immediately appear.

But now that I added the id column, when I add a date and content and press submit, the date and content would show up immediately but so should the id but for some reason it does not.

I've tried everything and cannot figure out why the **id has a delay.** 
The only way for me to get the id to show is by refreshing the page.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated! 
Thank you!

---

**Before**
[image: Before]

---

**After**
[image: After]

---

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="insertController">
    <h2> What I learned today </h2>
    <form>
      Date <br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="date"><br><br>
      Content <br>
      <textarea rows="10" cols="50" ng-model="content"></textarea><br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="insertdata()">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="fetchController"><br>
    <span ng-repeat="item in results">
      <div class="card">
        id: {{item.id}}<br>
        <span class="bold-underline">{{item.date}}</span><br>
        {{item.content}}
        <button class="deleteButton" ng-click="deleteThisItem()"> x </button>
      </div>
      <br><br>
    </span>
  </div>

</body>
```

---

**fetch.php**

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // clientside(Node) <-> serverside(PHP)

  $theConnection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "storestuff");

  if($theConnection->connect_error) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", $theConnection->connect_error);
    exit();
  }

  $query = "SELECT * FROM thestuff";
  $theData = array();

  if($result = $theConnection->query($query)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $theData[] = array(
        'id'=>$row['id'],
        'date'=>$row['date'],
        'content'=>$row['content']);
    }
    echo json_encode($theData); // Echo the output for the controller to access
    $result->free(); // Free the result set
  }
  else {
    echo "0 results.";
  }
  $theConnection->close(); // Close the connection
?>
```

---

**fetchController.js**

```
var size = 0;
var count = 0;

app.controller('fetchController', function ($scope, $http, resultsService) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/storestuff/fetch.php')
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
      size = (response.data).length;
      while(count < size) {
        var id = response.data[count].id;
        var date = response.data[count].date;
        var content = response.data[count].content;
        resultsService.addItem(id, date, content);
        count++;
      }
      size = 0;
      count = 0;
      $scope.results = resultsService.getItems();
  });
});
```

---

**Result.js**

```
app.service('resultsService', function() {
  var results = new Array();

  var addItem = function(id, date, content) {
    var obj = new Object();
    obj['id'] = id;
    obj['date'] = date;
    obj['content'] = content;
    results.push(obj);
  }

  var getItems = function() {
    return results;
  }

  var deleteItem = function() {

  }

  return {
    addItem: addItem,
    getItems: getItems,
    deleteItem: deleteItem
  };

});
```

---

**insert.php**

```
<?php

  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

  $theConnection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "storestuff");
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL.";
  }

  $theData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
  $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($theConnection, $theData->date);
  $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($theConnection, $theData->content);

  mysqli_query($theConnection, "INSERT INTO thestuff(date, content) VALUES('$date', '$content')");

  mysqli_close($theConnection);

?>
```

---

**insertController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('insertController', function($scope, $http, resultsService) {
  $scope.insertdata = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/storestuff/insert.php',
      data: {'date':$scope.date, 'content':$scope.content, 'in':'json-format'},
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log("Successful response", res)
      resultsService.addItem($scope.date, $scope.content);
      $scope.date = "";
      $scope.content = "";
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error("Error with POST", err);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Show the code invoked when user submits a form.

Comment: Where is the code that inserts the row? Do you call it via AJAX, and if so, does it return the inserted data, or are you just reloading the whole list with fetch.php?

Comment: Added the submit form code!
Sorry for the inconvenience guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `insertController` you are missing `id` parameter

```
resultsService.addItem($scope.date, $scope.content); //wrong
```

hence date is getting assigned to `id`.

Correct: 
`resultsService.addItem(res.id, $scope.date, $scope.content);`

Comment: +1, but problem. `alert(res);` shows [object Object] and `alert(JSON.stringify(res.data))` shows "". The promise response seems to be empty. Do you have any suggestions as to why? I looked everywhere but can't find out why. Thanks!

Comment: This is not the conventional way of doing it... I know... But it works... Could you suggest something better for me please? Thanks man! http://i.imgur.com/h4IT2zO.png

Comment: Soon after insert, send created result to UI so that you can save one backed call. You are right now fetching again which is not needed.